# How can I dump data from tables with composite PK/FKs into similar tables Using ID/FK

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table that needs a composite PK:

```
Table1
+---------+---------+
|  CompA  |  CompB  |
+---------+---------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 |
| Value 1 | Value 3 |
| Value 2 | Value 3 |
+---------+---------+
```

I then built a second table, and wanted to use the PK from Table 1 as an FK in this new Table 2. There's two ways you can do this.

**Option 1** - And the option I originally went with is to just use the composite key from Table 1 as the FK in Table 2.

```
Table 2
+------+---------+---------+
| T2PK |  CompA  |  CompB  |
+------+---------+---------+
| A    | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| B    | Value 1 | Value 3 |
| C    | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| D    | Value 2 | Value 3 |
+------+---------+---------+
```

**Option 2** - The option I now want to transition to, is to change the PK in Table 1 to an ID column, and slap a composite UNIQUE constraint on the value pairs

```
Table 1
+----+---------+---------+
| ID |  CompA  |  CompB  |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | Value 1 | Value 2 |
|  2 | Value 1 | Value 3 |
|  3 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

So now, in any other tables you want to use Table 1 as an FK in, you reference the single ID column (since that is now Table 1's PK)

```
Table 2
+----+------+
| PK | T1FK |
+----+------+
| A  |    1 |
| B  |    2 |
| C  |    3 |
| D  |    3 |
+----+------+
```

**The problem** - I Originally built my tables with Option 1. Having FKs that span multiple columns for 1 entity has become annoying and makes my join statements more complicated than they need to be. I now want to transition to option 2. I have built the tables with option 2's methodology, but I cant figure out a nice way to dump my option 1 table's data into my new option 2 tables. I cant figure out how, After dumping `Table1, Option1`'s data into `Table1 Option2`'s table, and getting IDs generated, how to tie those generated IDs to the same set of `Table2 Option1`'s data to the new `Table2 Option2`

Comment: Oracle  11g Sorry

Comment: Can't you generate a ID with ROW_NUMBER() over the multiple columns and use it as PK?

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions144.htm#SQLRF06100

Comment: Surprisingly not finding any duplicates (well, some stuff with EntityFramework).  Maybe by the time this becomes an issue it tends to be worked on by somebody who has enough experience.  [Related, but OP is apparently past this point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145413/how-to-migrate-from-a-composite-primary-key-to-a-single-attribute-key-in-sql).  Essentially, the important thing is generating a table that contains **both** the old and new keys, at least temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming that we have these "old" tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
  CompA varchar2(10), CompB  varchar2(10), constraint Table1_pk primary key(CompA,CompB)
);

Insert all
into Table1 values('Value 1', 'Value 2')
into Table1 values('Value 1', 'Value 3')
into Table1 values('Value 2', 'Value 3')
SELECT null FROM dual;

CREATE TABLE Table2(
  T2PK varchar2(1),
  CompA varchar2(10), CompB  varchar2(10), 
  constraint Table2_fk foreign key(CompA,CompB) references table1(CompA,CompB)
);

Insert all
into Table2 values('A', 'Value 1', 'Value 2')
into Table2 values('B', 'Value 1', 'Value 3')
into Table2 values('C', 'Value 2', 'Value 3')
into Table2 values('D', 'Value 2', 'Value 3')
SELECT null FROM dual;
```

we can migrate to "new" tables using below code:

```
CREATE TABLE new_Table1(
   ID int PRIMARY KEY,
   CompA varchar2(10), CompB  varchar2(10), 
   constraint new_Table1_uq unique(CompA,CompB)
);

INSERT INTO new_Table1( id, CompA, CompB)
SELECT rownum, CompA, CompB FROM Table1;

CREATE TABLE new_Table2(
   PK  varchar2(1),
   T1FK int,
   constraint new_Table2_fk foreign key(T1FK) references new_Table1( id )
);

INSERT INTO new_Table2( PK , T1FK )
SELECT t2.T2PK, t1.ID
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN new_Table1 t1 
ON t2.CompA = t1.CompA AND t2.CompB = t1.CompB;
```

Here is a working demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=32e852ab929c9431cce31495745ec6ba

Comment: Not blaming you for not answering sooner since SO answers are altruistic in nature (IMO), but god I wish I had seen this sooner. I figured out a much worse solution myself using DISGUSTING joins between the old tables and new tables but this solution is so elegant. Thanks I will use this in the future if I find myself in the same scenario.

Comment: @Rosey . . . This is essentially the same as my answer, which was posted earlier.  I mean, the demo is a good addition, but your comment is quite curious.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can assign the id using `row_number()` or rownum:

```
create table new_table1 as
    select rownum as table1_id, compA, compB
    from table1;
```

You can then use this as:

```
create table new_table2 as
    select t2.id, t2.table1_id
    from table2 t2 left join  -- outer join just in case you have NULL values
         new_table1 t1
         on t2.compA = t1.compA and t2.compB = t1.compB;
```

Comment: I think the important thing to mention to OP is they have to renumber **and keep the original keys**, at least for the duration of the migration.  Their primary problem is that they're attempting to create the new table without the old keys, which gives them nothing to reference for the second table